# Can i set/change the return value of a mock after the mock is defined?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit4

**I want to create a mock in my setUp method**, but define the concrete return values in each test method.. is this somehow possible?

Ex:

```
private List<Long> list; 

@Before
public void setUp() {
    when(mock.xxx()).thenReturn(list);
}

@Test
public void testEmptyList() {
    list = new ArrayList<Long>();

    // method call
}

@Test
public void testWithOneElement() {
    list = Arrays.asList(Long.valueOf(125L));

    // method call
}
```

**Edit**:
Best case i could have is this:

```
private List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();

@Before
public void setUp() {
    when(mock.xxx()).thenReturn(list);
}

@Test
public void testEmptyList() {
    // method call
}

@Test
public void testWithOneElement() {
    list.add(Long.valueOf(123L));
    // method call
}
```

Since Java passes value by Reference, as long as we do not **assign** a new list to the list, we can add values, and mock will work with the updated list. 
But is this kind of behaviour somehow possible even with the changed ObjectIds? So i mock a method call, but define what to return later?

Ex:

```
private List<Long> list; 

@Before
public void setUp() {
    when(mock.xxx()).thenReturn(list);
}

@Test
public void testEmptyArrayList() {
    list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    // method call
}

@Test
public void testEmptyLinkedList() {
    list = new LinkedList<Long>();
    // method call
}
```

Comment: You can add `when(mock.xxx()).thenReturn(list);` to both your testcase separately and not in setUp(). then return emplty list in testEmpty and return list with one element in testWithOneElement

Comment: I would go with more explicit code - mocking different returns closer to the place where they need as Foolish suggests.

Comment: obviously i am aware of that... i explicitly asked this question, so that i dont have to mock separately, because i have many test methods, not just 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. after some trial and error, I have made sth like this:

```
private List<Long> list; 

@Before
public void setUp() {
    when(mock.xxx()).thenAnswer(
            new Answer<List<Long>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Long> answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                    return list;
                }
            });
}

@Test
public void testEmptyArrayList() {
    list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    // method call
}

@Test
public void testEmptyLinkedList() {
    list = new LinkedList<Long>();
    // method call
}
```

Since we now define in setUp, **not** "return value", **but** "the called method which prepares the return value", and since this method will be called at runtime first, we do not get a nullPointer, and the values we assign in each method will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can add when(mock.xxx()).thenReturn(list); to both your testcase separately and not in setUp(). then return emplty list in testEmpty and return list with one element in testWithOneElement

```
private List<Long> list; 

@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Other setup here
}

@Test
public void testEmptyList() {
    list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    when(mock.xxx()).thenReturn(list); // return list with no element

    // method call
}

@Test
public void testWithOneElement() {
    list = Arrays.asList(Long.valueOf(125L));
    when(mock.xxx()).thenReturn(list);  // return list with one elemet

    // method call
}
```

Comment: obviously i am aware of that... i explicitly asked this question, so that i dont have to mock separately, because i have many test methods, not just 2...

Comment: btw, you have to set the attribute list, before your mock definition! In your case you have a nullpointerexception.

Comment: You should mention that you are aware and looking for other option than this. And yes already commented in code to return empty list and with one element.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion though. But i already wrote "I want to create a mock in my setUp method".. not "i want to mock anywhere"

Comment: And you have to ASSIGN list before your mock definition! In your case you have a nullpointerexception.. "list = new ArrayList...."  and after that  "when(mock.xxx())...."